# For comprehension with conditions

Tags: scala

I have existing code which calls multiple futures. Example:

```
val result = for {
      _ <- future1 // Fire and forget call
      r2 <- future2
      r3 <- future3
    } yield (r2,r3)
```

What I would like to do is that I would like to conditionally do `_ <- future1`. What I would like to do is

```
val result = for {
          if(shouldFireAndForget) {_ <- future1 }// Fire and forget call
          r2 <- future2
          r3 <- future3
        } yield (r2,r3)
```

The `shouldFireAndForget` value is a boolean which can be read from a config file for example. If its set to `true` I want to make the `future1` call and if `false` I don't want to. The above code is clearly incorrect but I am confused how to do this without duplicating a bunch of code. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: y not keep future1 in separate for-yield as  future2, future3 are separate ops and ur yielding only r2, r3 from above for-yield

Comment: You do know that if `future1` is a `val` that gets created elsewhere it will get executed whether you use it in a `for` or not?

Comment: To add to @Jasper-M and @Aamir, calling `future1` in the for-comp will not "fire and forget", since it will wait for its completion to keep going.

Comment: @CyrilleCorpet Actually the other futures will not wait for `future1`. They will start executing as soon as they are created. It is just that the `result` will be composed from the `success` of three independent futures.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh I was assuming that `future1` was not instantiated before this call (might be only defined, with `def` or `lazy val`), otherwise the question makes no sense (since OP doesn't want the call to be made in some cases)

Answer (score 4):

You could try something like this:

```
val result = for {
  _ <- if (!shouldFireAndForget) future1 else Future.successful(())
  r2 <- future2
  r3 <- future3
} yield (r2,r3)
```

The "trick" is that the result of the `if`, which must be a future in either case.

Answer (score 2):

Well... there are few important point which need to be understood here.

lets say your have following code,

```
val future1 = Future{...}
val future2 = Future{...}
val future3 = Future{...}
```

What you need to know is that these futures start executing as soon as you do `val futureX = Future{...}`, whether you use them again somewhere or not.

Now looking at your original code,

```
val result = for {
  _ <- future1 // Fire and forget call
  r2 <- future2
  r3 <- future3
} yield (r2,r3)
```

Here, `future1` is not actually "fire and forget". Your `result` will succeed if and only if all of `future1`, `future2` and `future3` succeed. If any of the 3 `fails` your `result` will fail as well. And as you said `future1` is "fire and forget", I don't think you want your `result` to fail if `future1` fails.

If you truly want your `result` to be free of "fire and forget" `future1` then you should do something like this,

```
if (fireAndForget) {
  val future1 = Future{...}
}

val result = for {
  r2 <- Future{...}
  r3 <- Future{...}
} yield (r2,r3)
```

Comment: To be more precise, instantiation of a `Future` (eg with `val`) does not start execution there and then, but only as soon as the `ExecutionContext` sees fit (when a thread is freed, for instance).